# Google Map Theme Styling

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using [Styled Map Wizard](http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to set up the JSON for my map's styles. But our client would like to make any bike or walk trail be dotted lines. I can’t seem to find a way to make the trails dotted lines. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is:

## [Dashed lines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#dashed_lines)

> You can achieve a dashed line effect by setting the opacity of your polyline to 0, and overlaying an opaque symbol over the line at regular intervals.

Sample Code

```
// Define a symbol using SVG path notation, with an opacity of 1.
var lineSymbol = {
path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
strokeOpacity: 1,
scale: 4
};

// Create the polyline, passing the symbol in the 'icons' property.
// Give the line an opacity of 0.
// Repeat the symbol at intervals of 20 pixels to create the dashed effect.
var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: [{lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027}, {lat: 18.291, lng: 153.027}],
strokeOpacity: 0,
icons: [{
icon: lineSymbol,
offset: '0',
repeat: '20px'
}],
map: map
});
```

Hope this Helps